# How to match records for two different groups?

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, grouping

I have one main table called Event_log which contains all of the records that I need for this query.  Within this table there is one column that I'm calling "Grp".  To simplify things, assume that there are only two possible values for this Grp: A and B.  So now we have one table, Event_log, with one column "Grp" and one more column called "Actual Date".  Lastly I want to add one more Flag column to this table, which works as follows.

First, I order all of the records in descending order by date as demonstrated below.  Then, I want to flag each Group "A" row with a 1 or a 0.  For all "A" rows, if the previous record (earlier in date) = "B" row then I want to flag 1.  Otherwise flag a 0.  So this initial table looks like this before setting this flag:

```
Actual Date         Grp           Flag
1-29-13             A
12-27-12           B
12-26-12           B
12-23-12           A
12-22-12           A
```

But after these calculations are done, it should look like this:

```
Actual Date         Grp           Flag
1-29-13             A              1
12-27-12           B               NULL
12-26-12           B               NULL
12-23-12           A               0
12-22-12           A               0
```

How can I do this?  This is simpler to describe than it is to query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
select el.ActualDate
  , el.Grp
  , Flag = case 
    when el.grp = 'B' then null
    when prev.grp = 'B' then 1
    else 0
    end
from Event_log el
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 prev.grp
    from Event_log prev
    where el.ActualDate > prev.ActualDate
    order by prev.ActualDate desc
  ) prev
order by el.ActualDate desc
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e83a1/2).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
;with cte as
(

  SELECT CAST('01-29-13' As DateTime) ActualDate,'A' Grp
  UNION ALL SELECT '12-27-12','B'
  UNION ALL SELECT '12-26-12','B'
  UNION ALL SELECT '12-23-12','A'
  UNION ALL SELECT '12-22-12','A'
)
, CTE2 as 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by actualdate desc) rn
  FROM cte
)
SELECT a.*, 
case 
 when A.Grp = 'A' THEN 
      CASE WHEN b.Grp = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 ELSE NULL
END Flag   
from cte2 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 b on a.rn + 1 = b.rn
```